# A method to construct a contains lambda expression from a list of properties and values

Tags: c#, lambda

I am attempting to write a method that will construct a contains type lambda expression that I can tack on to my queries like `qry.Where(lambda)`.

I am pretty new to expression trees and am running into trouble.
Here is what I have so far:

```
        public static IQueryable<T> ContainsQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, IEnumerable<string> propertyValues)
                {
                    ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
                    MethodInfo indexOf = typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });

                    foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
                    {
                        foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
                        {

                        }
                    }
    ... 
return query.Where(lambda);
                }
```

I know that I need the case insensitive indexOf to do the comparison and I know that I need to loop for all the properties and all the values (think searching for one or more values in one or more columns of a table and returning the or'd result of all the combinations.

I am just having trouble getting started constructing this.

Comment: Can you give an example for the expression you want to build? Actually, let the C# compiler build it for you and see how it's done.

Comment: @usr I would like for it to be something equivelent to the sql statement: where colA like %valueA% or colB like %valueA% or colA like %valueB% or colB like %valueB% etc. for columns and all values. I didn't understand the second part of letting the compiler build it for me. Can you expand on that?

Comment: Sure. Compile `Expression<Func<bool>> x = () => str.Contains("a") || str.Contains("b");` and then decompile the binary. There you can see what such an expression looks like. Isn't it your problem that you don't know how to build such an expression?

Comment: @usr How do I do what you are describing. I do not know how to do both steps. Should I just set up a console app and then compile? Where do I find the binary and how do I decompile it?

Comment: Yes, just put this code into any method and shove the compiled DLL or EXE into Reflector or dotPeek. I know that this works with Reflector. You will see calls to the Expression.* methods.